# SFDX Force:org:open fails and user is directed to the login screen

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, winter19

I have two scratch orgs that I've created this week, post Winter Release, that will not open from the command line using sfdx force:org:open.  The login fails and I'm stuck staring at the login screen.  Another dev on my team just experienced the same issue.  Has anyone else?

Comment: Could you add more details on this ?

Comment: Sure - I created a new scratch org yesterday through the command line.  I open the scratch org to make changes directly through Salesforce UI.  Close the browser.  The next time I try to open my scratch org via the command line:
sfdx force:org:open a browser window opens, but I get the failed login attempt instead, as if it's a bad password error.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue with a scratch org I created yesterday, but no others. I wasn't even able to get the sfdx force:org:open command to work the first time. I was able to login by using the force:user:password:generate command and logging in the old-fashioned way.

Comment: I just created a scratch org today and that one works fine. I think I may have figured out the issue and will post an answer momentarily.

Comment: I can confirm that this is still happening. Once the redirect has taken you to 'test.salesforce.com', you can change the address to your domain, eg 'power-ability-9295-dev-ed.lightning.force.com' and you will be able to log in again.

Answer (score 9):

I also experienced this issue this week and, while I'm not sure of the cause of it, I believe it has something to do with the URL that is generated by the SFDX CLI. This might be a bug that can be filed with the SFDX team. (**Update:** According to Salesforce, "we are pushing a fix in this weeks CLI release.")

**Failing Example**

For the scratch org that doesn't auto log me in from the CLI via `sfdx force:org:open -u [OrgName]`, this message is generated:

```
Access org ### as user test-[removed]@example.com with the following URL: https://cs50.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=[removed]
```

**Working Example**

For the scratch org that works as expected, this message is generated:

```
Access org ### as user test-[removed]@example.com with the following URL: https://computing-ruby-1278-dev-ed.cs24.my.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=[removed]
```

In the example output where the CLI command works, notice that the My Domain is included in the URL (computing-ruby-1278-dev-ed)

**Solution**

If you grab the My Domain part of the URL when redirected to the login page, you should be able to login successfully by modifying the generated URL to include the My Domain.

**Alternative Solution**

An alternative solution is to generate a password for the user via the `sfdx force:user:password:generate` command and logging in that way.

Comment: I posted this Q&A to the Salesforce DX group: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1

Comment: Thank you so much.... I've just used this workaround successfully!

Comment: This work around is not working for me.

Answer (score 5):

We are in the process of fixing this issue and will be pushing the fix by the end of next week.

Comment: who is 'we' ? possible to disclose your affiliation and or udpate your profile, thanks =)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Claire! Hope you don't mind but I checked your email address and I can confirm that Claire is from Salesforce :)

Comment: Yes, sorry I am the PM for the Salesforce CLI.

Comment: @ClaireBianchi - FYI, this just happened to me today (2nd Nov). Workaround below resolved it.. on latest DX CLI.

Comment: @ClaireBianchi - This is still happening (or happening again) Feb 07, 2019.  See:  https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A000049pDtB   Was there ever a fix for this?

Comment: Thank you for alerting me. Did the issue go away and come back or is this the first time you have tried in a while?

Comment: @ClaireBianchi - Last week was the first time I had seen the issue.

Comment: Still happening Robert Watsons solution allows login.

Comment: What I noticed is sometimes redirect after frontdoor login fail takes to test.salesforce.com instead of login.salesforce.com, this could be the reason of login failure.

Comment: Still happening... any update on SF progress on that?